# Apache Solr: How to add all the dynamic fileds to the stats.field

Tags: apache, solr, solr-query-syntax

I am new to apache solr, I need some help regarding a query. I have created some dynamic fields in solr schema which vary document to document. Now I need to run a query where I can get all the dynamic fields under the stats section to create a filter so that i can run filter queries on the searched result.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/catalog/select?fq=color_sm%3A(*%22black%22)&q=product_name%3AMouse&stats=true&stats.calcdistinct=true&stats.field=height_sm&stats.field=color_sm&stats.field=height_i&rows=0
```

in above query there are few dynamic fields with suffix _sm and i want all the fields having same suffix in the search result under stats section.

Following is the output of above query, but stats_fields is listing only those columns I've defined in query, there are some more dynamic columns which i wants to be in result json but it shouldn't be defined in query separately.

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 2,
    "params": {
      "q": "product_name:Mouse",
      "stats.calcdistinct": "true",
      "stats": "true",
      "fq": "color_sm:(*\"black\")",
      "rows": "0",
      "stats.field": [
        "height_sm",
        "color_sm"
      ]
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 10,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [

    ]
  },
  "stats": {
    "stats_fields": {
      "height_sm": {
        "min": "30 Centimeters",
        "max": "45 Centimeters",
        "count": 2,
        "missing": 0,
        "distinctValues": [
          "30 Centimeters",
          "45 Centimeters"
        ],
        "countDistinct": 2
      },
      "color_sm": {
        "min": "Black",
        "max": "White",
        "count": 3,
        "missing": 0,
        "distinctValues": [
          "Black",
          "Gray",
          "White"
        ],
        "countDistinct": 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need some help to solve this, kindly let me know if solr allows to do so and if yes then how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to define dynamic fields as `stats.field`.

See how they use `stats.field={!func}termfreq('text','memory')` in the [Solr Stats Component example](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/the-stats-component.html#stats-component-example):

`http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=*:*&wt=xml&stats=true&stats.field={!func}termfreq('text','memory')&stats.field=price&stats.field=popularity&rows=0&indent=true`